# Can Readiness, Liveness check made active/inactive by configuration

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am playing around with Quarkus and I am trying to create ingestion service, which sends data to kafka or another REST endpoint. I have added "quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka" and "quarkus-reactive-messaging-http" dependencies to the project. I wanted to have only one particular pipeline ie http->kafka or http->http at a time, but I should be able to change that using configuration update followed by restart. I could achieve this by adding 2 dependencies and configurations as shown below

```
## Rest service configuration
mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.connector=smallrye-http
mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.method=POST
mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.url=http://localhost:9009/messages

## Kafka Ingestion configuration
## ----------------------------
#mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.connector=smallrye-kafka
#kafka.bootstrap.servers=host.docker.internal:9092
#mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.topic=messages
#mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

Now the problem is that even though I have Kafka connector commented out in my application.propertues, the health check for Kafka still runs and shows that Kafka is down. I expect that it should not have run the Kafka health check since I don't have configured as per the configuartion. Is this possible now and if not does it make sense to consider it as feature request and include it ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Health check for Kafka is disabled by default.

But the health check for reactive messaging is enabled by default, you can disable it via `mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.heath-enabled=false`.

Note that, for your use case, you can also use different channels and disabling the one you didn't use instead of commenting out the configuration.

Disabling a channel can be done simply via `mp.messaging.outgoing.messages.enabled=false`.

Comment: Thank you @loicmathieu. Using different channels would be the most suitable approach for me.